# Problem with ubuntu 15.10 after dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 15.10, windows-10

I dual booted my windows 10 pc with ubuntu 15.10. It worked fine for a couple of weeks but now it's stopped, i boot up with the ubuntu system and login and when that's done nothing happens. You can move around the cursor and see the wallpaper of the os. Also when i type something a little box in the bottom-right corner appears and starts showing the letters I've typed (kind of like a 'find in page' or 'ctrl+f' on a browser but without anything but the cursor and the background.) Thank you in advance for the help! :)

Comment: Screen shot, what you did last time that might have caused this to happen?

Comment: i cant screenshot

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then

```
setsid unity
```

[image]
It will fix problems like no side bar etc...and only mouse clicks working

Comment: i cant start a terminal, will it work if i use the grub?